# How to fill a webpage with an iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I need a way to fill the entire webpage with an iframe.
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   body{ margin:0px; width:100%; height:100%; }
   iframe{width:100%; height:95%; border:none;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <iframe src="http://www.repubblica.it/"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/8nh3kfws/1/

As you can see, the iframe doesn't fill the entire page but there is a big white space in the bottom. I have noticed that it works if I remove `"<!DOCTYPE html>"` but I don't know why.

So, How can I do it without removing `"<!DOCTYPE html>"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `html` to your style declaration.

```
html, body{ margin:0px; width:100%; height:100%; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8nh3kfws/2/

Comment: And maybe add `overflow: hidden`, otherwise you end up with two scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a position to your iframe.

```
iframe{width:100%; height:95%; border:none; position: absolute}
```